# How does `if ( __some_bool__ != NULL )` behave?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, conditional-statements, comparison-operators

I was refactoring some code, when I came across some code that looked like this:

```
if( __some_bool__ != NULL ) {
    .....do something......
    }
```

Where `__some_bool__` is a `bool`. I don't mean the `BOOL` that's `typedef`'d in the Windows headers.

This is most definitely **NOT** what (the programmer who wrote this) intended. But, before actually fixing it, I'd like to make sure I'm not breaking anything.

How will that evaluate? does `false` == `NULL`? What kind of coercion is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NULL is usually defined as integer 0. And §4.7/4 from the C++ Standard says (Integral Conversion):

> If the source type is bool, the value `false` is converted to zero and
>   the value `true` is converted to one.

Conversion between `bool` and integer is implicit in C++. The rest is obvious. Typical programmer would replace this as simple:

```
if( __some_bool__ ) {
    // do something
}
```